# load dropdown only when its clicked

Tags: asp.net

I have 1 independent and 3 dependent dropdowns in my page. loading all ddlvalues initially takes more time and even for every ddl index change, other dependent ddl takes more time to load ..

Pls help me to find a solution.
I tried to load my page initially with no values except --All-- with index 0 in all dropdowns.only when a dropdown is clicked it should load the data from dataset taking previous ddl value if required.

Then I found 'Onclick' option missing in ddl. so I used 
   `ddlGM.Attributes.add("OnClick",javascriptfunction)` I'm not sure where to place this code in ma page.
and what java script to write in that..

Could you pls help me..
below is my code...
------------my design page code------------------

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    //    $(dropdownloads).click(function() {
    //    clickHiddenButton();
    //});
     //$(document).ready(function () {

        function clickHiddenButton() {
        //var ddl = dropdownloads.getElementById('ddlGM');
        //if (ddl.click) 

           var btn = dropdownloads.getElementById('btnHidden');
            btn.click();

    }
    //})
</script>


<td>
  <asp:Label ID="GM"  runat="server" Text="Global Market" ></asp:Label></td>
<td>
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGM"    
     Width="150px" AutoPostBack="True" class="dropdownloads"
    onselectedindexchanged="ddlGM_SelectedIndexChanged" style="height:22px">
    <asp:ListItem Value=0 Text="All"></asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
         <div style="display: none;" >
                    <asp:Button ID="btnHidden" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnHidden_Click"  />

                </div></td>

 <td ><asp:Label ID="Horizontal" runat="server" Text="Horizontal"></asp:Label></td>  
 <td>< asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHori" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="150px" onselectedindexchanged="ddlHori_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value=0 Text="All"></asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList></td>

<td>< asp:Label ID="BU" runat="server" Text="BU"></asp:Label></td>   
<td>< asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBU" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="150px" onselectedindexchanged="ddlBU_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value=0 Text="All"></asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList></td>

<td>< asp:Label ID="SBU1" runat="server" Text="SBU"></asp:Label></td>
<td>< asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSBU1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="150px" onselectedindexchanged="ddlSBU1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value=0 Text="All"></asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList></td>
```

------------my .cs page code-----------------

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlGM.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "dropdownload()");

          if (!IsPostBack)
          {  FillAccounts();
           }
  }

   protected void btnHidden_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    DataView dvfilters = (DataView)(Cache["FiltersData"]);
    dtt = dvfilters.ToTable();
    ddlGM.DataSource = dtt;
    ddlGM.DataValueField = "GlobalMarket";

    ddlGM.DataBind();
    RemoveDuplicateItems(ddlGM);
    SortDDL(ref ddlGM);
    //ddlGM.Items.Insert(0, "All");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
If(buttonClicked) {
   // Sets the data in the ddl
   dropdownList.DataSource = yourDataSource;
} else {
   // Clears (removes) all ites in the ddl
   dropdownList.Items.Clear();
}
```

Or, if you mean when a item is selected from 1 ddl:

```
foreach(ListItem item in ddl.Items) {
    // If the value is selected in the dropdownlist
    If(item.Selected) {
       // Sets the data in the ddl
       dropdownList.DataSource = yourDataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi..
I request like..when a dropdown is clicked ..on that click action I have to call hiddenbtn_click(); and load the dropdownlist.                           ddl.click()  {    hiddenbtn_click(); }

Comment: try: `dropdownList.Attributes.Add("onclick", "hiddenbtn_click()");`

Comment: may I know where should I have this above code..initially I had in Pageload()

Comment: It should be in your Page_Load, yes. 
Try debug it and look if your method is called. (So is the ddl filled with data, assuming your method hiddenbtn_click() works well). Please share the result(s) after debugging.